# how should I integrate recaptcha in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, recaptcha

I want to integrate recaptcha in registration form in Codeigniter. The form will post in ajax. Please help me..

thanks in advance

Comment: Please modify your question with the code snippets you are using. It is a good question but you have less description. I suggest you to edit and submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find your solution.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Find there

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

You will also find a demo here.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax

Answer (score 0):

There are several link in google where you can find how to integrate recaptcha in codeigniter

http://www.99points.info/2010/04/how-to-use-re-captcha-in-codeigniter-based-website/

http://www.christophermonnat.com/2008/09/how-to-use-recaptcha-with-ci/

http://blog.markmirandilla.com/2011/09/17/how-to-integrate-recaptcha-with-codeigniter/

**ALSO SEE :-** [Recaptcha in Codigniter](https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-recaptcha)