# G-recaptcha in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

I don't know how to call google snippet re-captcha in controller form.php and set url with secret key
I have file form_view.php where i paste google snippet code :

`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>`

then in controllers/form.php i validate form and also call google recaptcha like this

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('g-recaptcha', 'Google Captcha', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_checkCaptcha');`

The result is, if i check or uncheck google re-captcha, message is the same :

**Array Google Captcha is requiered** but it loads captcha from CodeIgniter but not google re-captcha.

Thanks for help guys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168002/how-should-i-integrate-recaptcha-in-codeigniter

Comment: I saw that thread but I dont know how to code Configuration

Comment: check the code step by step it's easy to adding the code in config file with the keys

Comment: http://www.tutsmore.com/tutorials/google-new-recaptcha-example-for-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library code https://github.com/Cnordbo/RECaptcha-for-Codeigniter the functions are ready to use, you only need the secret-key and the public-key that google give to you in this page https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html